# MVVM Binding View specific DataType

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture

I want to know how you would bind a View specific data type to your View from a ViewModel.

To be more concrete I have a ContextMenu as part of a DatagridView. Now I can bind the ItemSource of my ContextMenu to either a List of MenuItems or a List of Strings (<= implementing a Converter on this).

Both options work fine, but I want to know which is the best and why. I am asking cause I have read that I should try to not use the System.Windows.* Namespace in my ViewModel, and when I Bind a List of MenuItems of course I use this Namespace but on the other Hand if I bind strings and just convert it... This feels weird.

SampleCode (using Caliburn):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="OverviewItems">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding AllColumns, Converter={StaticResource String_Menu_Converter}}" >
        <!-- Alternative: <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding AllColumns}" >-->
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event Click]=[SetVisibilityExecute($_clickeditem)]" />
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, we manipulate *data* object, not *UI objects*. So it is true that you should not have any UI objects in your view model. The correct way to get around this issue is to manipulate *data objects* in the view model that we can then data bind with the UI controls that we declare in `DataTemplate`s. So in your case, you could have a collection of custom objects that have a property to bind to the `MenuItem.Header` property and another to bind to the `MenuItem.Command` property for example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourCustomType}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
</DataTemplate>

...

<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding YourCustomTypeCollection}" />
```

Comment: It is not realy working, but this is not your fault I think its the fault of the Caliburn way of Binding Commands. 

I understand now how i should manage this, thank you!